# Getting the correct URL when using Jquery .prop() or .data()

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, href

I am trying to get the url of an image inside a modal popup when using [Bootstrap image gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery). Since the image is dynamically loaded, I need to get the url for that image to be able to share it. With this code I get "undefined" as my result:

```
  $('#modal-gallery').on('load', function () {
    var modalData = $(this).data('modal'),
    // The current, associated link element:
    linkElement = modalData.$links[modalData.options.index],
    url = $(linkElement).prop('href');      
  $(".info").html("<a href='http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php' class='addthis_button_compact' addthis:url='" + url + "'>" + "</a>");
   //addthis code   
   addthis.toolbox('.info');
  });
```

If I use this code, I get an href but it is in the form "slides/image.jpg" rather than "http://www.example.com/slides/image.jpg"

```
 $('#modal-gallery').on('load', function () {
  var modalData = $(this).data('modal'),
    // The current, associated link element:
    linkElement = modalData.$links[modalData.options.index],
    url = $(linkElement).data("href");      
  $(".info").html("<a href='http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php' class='addthis_button_compact' addthis:url='" + url + "'>" + "</a>");
addthis.toolbox('.info');
 });
```

Comment: You want the href of the link or the src of the image? Two different things.

Comment: I need the link to the image src. addthis needs the link added to addthis:url="". With my 2nd code block, I get the result _addthis:url="slides/image.jpg"_ when I need _addthis:url='http://www.example.com/slides/image.jpg'_

Comment: Sorry, this is the code:
`addthis:url="slides/image.jpg"`when I need `addthis:url="http://www.example.com/slides/image.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the image's src *property* instead of its attribute, you'll get full url:

Simple example:

```
$("#pic").get(0).src
```

Same principle applies to anchor tags. To get the absolute URL they're pointing to:

```
$("#link").get(0).href
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work in my specific case. Not sure how I can use ID's in a dynamically loaded image since there are no ID's? I guess I need to see how this fit's into my code

Comment: The IDs were only included as an example. The appropriate selector should of course be applied. Did I miss something in your question?

Comment: More likely it is my lack of jquery knowledge. I'm not seeing how i get from
` url = $(linkElement).prop('href'); ` 
to ` $("#link").get(0).href `

Comment: Try these. One of them might be what you are looking for: $(linkElement).get(0).href or simply linkElement.href.

Comment: I had tried that and it shows undefined as a result. I appreciate the help. I'll keep playing with it.